# SetPixel sets pixel below desired point C++

Tags: c++, gdi+

I have the following code:

```
POINT p;

int main(void) {
  HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);

  while(!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1)) {
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    SetPixel(hdc, p.x, p.y, RGB(73, 214, 0));
  }
  DeleteObject(hdc);
}
```

What I want to achive is when I move mouse the pixel at curent cursor position changes its color until the program is stopped. However I see a few issues here:

The  pixel is drawn below cursor position (resolution?) and after some time all pixels changes to default color. How Can I resolve the problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: So you're just painting in the console window? What happens when it repaints itself?

Comment: Probably that's the reason they disappear.

Comment: `GetDC(NULL)` is the handle to desktop window, it should be cleaned up with `ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc)`, and you are not allowed to paint on it. I would suggest making a standard windows program for GUI programming, instead of messing around with the standard console.

Comment: One is screen coordinates, the other is logical coordinates within a device context. That's why they are in different places.

Comment: Thank you a lot. So better way is to create a window covering the entire screen and paint on it?

Comment: Yes, you have to make a GUI program. What you have there right now is a console program. It lets you draw on desktop, but that's not your window so it gets erased. You make a GUI program with its own Window, now you own that window and you can control what's on it. See C++ WinAPI, .Net, Qt, or other frameworks for making a Windows program.